# Sudden Unexplained Email To Case Workflow Failure

Tags: workflow, email2case

We have `On Demand Email-To-Case` set up in our org. We also have a package installed called `Simple Survey`. It added a `Datetime` field named `simplesurvey__Survey_Sent__c` to the `Case` object, and we reference that in the criteria for one of our workflows:

```
AND(Other_Criteria__c, ISNULL(simplesurvey__Survey_Sent__c))
```

Today, this workflow started blocking all inserts with:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY : The formula in the "Case: Send Simple Survey (Odd)" rule or process is invalid due to the following:
> Field 00N1400000B6zfB is inaccessible. Please review all fields referenced by the formula. Context: core.workflow.WorkflowFormulaContext

The field referenced by Id in the error message is the same one I mention above, namely `simplesurvey__Survey_Sent__c`. It is accessible by all profiles. Nothing in the `Setup Audit Trail` looks even peripherally related. I deactivated the workflow rule and I'm still getting the error.

I have already raised a case with support, but what could be going on here?

Comment: The question would seem to be, which field name belongs to `Field 00N1400000B6zfB` and why is it inaccessible? "Odd", isn't it? ;)

Comment: I see what you did there (har har). Yes, the field itself is actually accessible by all profiles. It's the field I left included in my criteria, I'll update my post for clarity.

Comment: So it's active in the database is what you're saying? Have to wonder if the metadata isn't corrupted or if there isn't an issue with your license for the app.

Comment: Did the package just get updated? I've seen similar things to this before when fields were no longer supported by the package

Comment: @cropredy Yeah actually it expired...thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue when a package was updated to Version Y from Version X and where Version Y no longer supported fields from Version X (that might be referenced in workflows, page layouts, etc.)

Comment: In this case, it was expired, but your suggestion led me down the path I needed to investigate. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson -  I remember being flummoxed by this problem and it took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: I still don't understand why deactivating the workflow rule didn't resolve the issue. Quite strange.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I remember I had to Hard Erase the field